# "error above occured in the p component". Array mapping in REACT

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to practice mapping array objects and i cannot for the life of me get this to display on scrimba mini-browser. I can console.log the array object but that's all. Am i overlooking anything? Thanks.

```
import React from 'react'
import man from './menitem.js'
class App  extends React.Component{
    constructor(){
    super()


    this.state = {Men:man} 
}
render(){
    const newman = this.state.Men.map(item =>  item={item} )
    const newman1 = newman.toString(newman)
 return(<div>
 <p>{newman}</p>
 </div>)

}
}

export default App
```

[Screenshot of application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AxAvH.png)

Comment: You call it an "array object", while yes technically in Javascript an array is an object, is the data an `Array` or an `Object`? Can you show structure?

Comment: `const newman = this.state.Men.map(item =>  item={item} )` What is this line supposed to do?

Comment: Hey, its supposed to be an object. I was basically trying to map my object into an array that could be display in the mini-browser on scrimba. I figured it out after messing with it. Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The function that you're passing to `.map` isn't getting you what you need. It should be something more like:

```
const newman = this.state.Men.map(item => (<p key={item}>{item}</p>));
```

then in your `return` statement:

```
return (
  <div>
    {newman}
  </div>
);
```

Comment: Yes you're right, the map function didn't make much sense to me at first but after fiddling with it I have a better understanding of the actual code structure. Thank you!